# Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia GT 650 working together on laptop

Tags: laptop, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, optimus

My new win7 Acer notebook has i5 CPU with Intel HD 4000 and Nvida GT650 GPU. Obviously monitor is plugged to Intel HD. In Nvidia control panel I can configure PhysX but that doesn't help. Windows system rating shows high gaming experience and average/low windows aero experience. What does that mean? Does my laptop use nvidia for games/3d apps nad Intel HD 4000 for aero? Should I disable Intel HD in bios, but how to plug monitor to nvidia? Or should I leave everything like now because everything works as it suppose to work?
Here is image capture of some states: http://oi47.tinypic.com/34p0qp4.jpg

Comment: Everything works as it is intended to, GT650 kicks in when needed, this saves battery time. You can disable Intel but battery run time will suffer.

Comment: The two graphics units share output hardware. Both graphics units draw to the same place.